# Find the minimum of the square of distance between $a=(u,\sqrt{2-u^2})$ and $b=(v,\frac{9}{v})$

Tags: inequality

> Find the minimum of the square of distance between
>   $a=(u,\sqrt{2-u^2})$ and $b=(v,\frac{9}{v})$

This is a preparation Question PUTNAM contest. The theme of the section is "inequality". I can not make the problem from inequality. Is anyone is able give me a hint (using inequalities)?

Actually I have $(u-v)^2+ (\sqrt{2-u^2}-\frac{9}{v})^2 \geq  (u-v+\sqrt{2-u^2}-\frac{9}{v})^2$ by Arithmetic and Geometric Means Inequalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although You have Solve it Using Geometrically.

Here We have to calculate Distance between the points  $\displaystyle A\left(u,\sqrt{2-u^2}\right)$ and $\displaystyle B\left(v,\frac{9}{v}\right)$

Means point $A$ lie on Circle $x^2+y^2=2$ and point $B$ lie on Hyperbola $xy=9$

So here Minimum Distance is along Common Normal of these two curves.

So here Which is a Line $y=x.$

[image]

Comment: Honestly, I have some difficulties understanding how to do even if it is clear from the graph that you provide. Could you explain in more detail the link between inequality and my normal vectors to the curves?